# How to connect a 3D head to a body?

Tags: unity, 3d-modeling

I am new to Unity, game-making, etc.

I have downloaded the trial version of Avatar Maker and a similar Unity plugin called Didimo Editor, with the hope of using their features to make game characters that look like real people, using photographs. They both do more or less what I want.

However, both tools output only heads, and do not connect them to 3D bodies. Avatar Maker has another plugin that allows for this, but it is only for male bodies and most of its features are not to my liking.

So my question is: how can I put these heads on working 3D bodies?

The trailer for Didimo Editor seems to confirm that it can, at least, and Avatar Maker is able to export its heads to OBJ, FBX and Prefab, so I'm assuming maybe there is a way to do that too.

Comment: Presumably you've tried exporting these heads to a 3D format, then welding them to a body model in a 3D modelling program, using all the normal mesh editing features of that program? Where specifically do you run into trouble trying to do that?

Comment: No I haven't even gotten that far.  Presumably that's where I'd start, though, I guess, if you've said that.

Comment: What 3D modelling program would you recommend, in this instance?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried unpaking the character that you what to use delete the head and atach the one you have on its place then just make them a pre fab again , i do the same but with robots or randomizing game characters, sorry or my bad english best i can think of , and as far i remember those softwares of this photo to 3d software end up being used in blender then from there you can make them good for youre unity if that its youre problem

Comment: Please consider adding punctuation and line breaks to make your answer easier to read.